# Stop Animation with CCDirector AFTER adding UIViewController to cocos2d scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to add a UIKit ViewController on top of a cocos2d scene. Everything works great, but I need to run `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation]` AFTER the UIKit view is loaded completely.

I push a button and have a 1 second transition to the new scene being loaded. I have tried adding `stopAnimation` to every callback in both the `UIViewController`(`ViewDidLoad`, `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`, etc) and the Cocos2d scene. What happens is the scene is loaded but the animation is stopped before the `UIViewController` is completely loaded, which prevents the view from loading at all.

I could set a timer for the transition duration and then call `stopAnimation` but I would rather not do it that way. Is there any sort of delegate method I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that method from your view controller's *viewDidLoad* method:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]stopAnimation];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It simply loads the cocos2d view and the UIKit view never shows up.